# How to skip @DateTimeFormat annotation in open-api-generator plugin

Tags: openapi, openapi-generator, springdoc-openapi-ui, springdoc-openapi-maven-plugin

I am trying to generate interface from yaml file using open api generator plugin. However while generating the interface an additional annotation @DateTimeFormatter is getting added for date field. Can someone help how to skip adding this DateTimeFormatter annotation in date field.

Using 6.0.1 open api version

Answer (score 0):

A possible (but quite heavy) solution would be to customize the mustache template that is used to generate such field (`dateTimeParam.mustache`)

https://github.com/OpenAPITools/openapi-generator/blob/master/modules/openapi-generator/src/main/resources/JavaSpring/dateTimeParam.mustache

You can configure Maven to use extra template(s) using:

```
<templateDirectory>${project.basedir}/openapi/templates</templateDirectory>
```

You can find an example [here](https://github.com/sigpwned/openapi-generator-maven-plugin-template-customization-example).